# How to save protected properties via datamapper to database?

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to grasp the concept of a datamapper (I hope this is the right terminology) in conjunction with protected properties.

I am building an authentication system. There I have a User class

```
class User {

protected $id;
public $first_name;
public $mail;
protected $password;
```

As you can see, I chose to make $id and $password protected. Actually I'm not quite sure if that's right, but I did read, that one should try to keep the scope of properties as closed as possible.

I also build a datamapper to save my user object to my database. The mapper is injected to the user class via constructor dependency injection. I call the mappers save-method from inside my user class this way

```
public function save () {
    return $this->dep['mapper']->saveUser($this);
}
```

Inside my mappers saveUser()-method I am building an array of values to pass along to my database class.

```
public function saveUser($obj) {

    $insert_array;

    foreach ( $obj as $key => $value ) {
        $insert_array[$key] = $obj->get($key);
    }
```

This does not work the way it's intended, because my mapper is not able to iterate over the protected properties. Therefore these properties are not passed on to the database. If the said properties are public it works just fine.

So my question is: How do I have to setup my classes and methods so that my mapper is able to get all the values it needs, without exposing all my properties?

Extra: I already made use of __get() to circumvent the problem, but is that good coding practice?

Comment: If there is anything worth knowing about the user object, it should be at least readable; otherwise, why save it? My usual approach is, when "saving an object", you save the input not necessarily the object properties, so you can bypass the "set properties on object, then read properties for saving" stage and just save the raw input. If a property needs to be processed by the user object before saving, it goes back to my first sentence--if it is worth knowing about, it should be readable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single right answer for this, but IMO you don't want to have different visibility for fields in a data object. Here are some ideas.

If you're set on having different visibility for fields on you User class, you can change things up like this to allow your Mapper to save the data using an array you build in the save method of your user class.

```
<?php

    class User
    {
        protected $id;
        public    $first_name;
        public    $mail;
        protected $password;

        private $dep = [];

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->dep['mapper'] = new Mapper();
        }

        public function save()
        {
            $data = [
                'id' => $this->id,
                'first_name' => $this->first_name,
                'mail' => $this->mail,
                'password' => $this->password
            ];

            return $this->dep['mapper']->saveUser($data);
        }
    }

    class Mapper
    {
        public function saveUser($data)
        {
            foreach($data as $field=>$value)
            {
                echo $field.': '.$value.PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }

    $myUser = new User();

    $myUser->first_name = 'Lando';
    $myUser->mail = 'lando@cloudcity.gov';

    $myUser->save();
```

A more formal option is to use a Data Transfer Object (DTO), which is a dead-simple class that just encapsulates the data. Then you can control access to the fields in your business object.

```
<?php

class User
{
    private $dto;
    private $dep = [];

    public function __construct(UserDto $dto)
    {
        $this->dto           = $dto;
        $this->dep['mapper'] = new Mapper();
    }

    public function __get($propName)
    {
        if($propName=='password')
        {
            throw new Exception('No password for you');
        }
        elseif(property_exists($this->dto, $propName))
        {
            return $this->dto->$propName;
        }

        throw new InvalidArgumentException('No property '.$propName.' found in object');
    }

    public function __set($propName, $value)
    {
        if($propName=='id')
        {
            throw new Exception('ID may not be changed');
        }
        elseif($propName=='password')
        {
            throw new Exception('Password may not be changed');
        }
        elseif(property_exists($this->dto, $propName))
        {
            $this->dto->$propName = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->$propName = $value;
        }
    }

    public function __isset($propName)
    {
        return (property_exists($this->dto, $propName));
    }

    public function save()
    {
        return $this->dep['mapper']->saveUser($this->dto);
    }
}

class UserDto
{
    public $id;
    public $first_name;
    public $mail;
    public $password;
}

class Mapper
{
    public function saveUser(UserDto $dto)
    {
        foreach ($dto as $key => $value)
        {
            $insert_array[$key] = $dto->$key;

            echo $key.': '.$value.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

try
{
    $dto    = new UserDto();
    $myUser = new User($dto);

    $myUser->first_name = 'Lando';
    $myUser->mail       = 'lando@cloudcity.gov';

    echo $myUser->password;
    $myUser->password = 'foobar';

    $myUser->save();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
}
```

A better option to control access to properties is by using get/set/has methods. This is verbose, but has the benefit of adding logic or transforms to the data as you get and set it. One of the major benefits of this approach is that full-featured code editors will code-complete all of these getters and setters, you don't get that with magic methods. You can of course use this in combination with DTOs.

```
<?php

class User
{
    private $data = [
        'id'=>null,
        'first_name'=>null,
        'mail'=>null,
        'password'=>null
    ];

    private $dep = [];

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $validData = array_intersect_key($data, $this->data);

        foreach($validData as $currKey=>$currValue)
        {
            $this->data[$currKey] = $currValue;
        }

        $this->dep['mapper'] = new Mapper();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->data['id'];
    }

    //Notice there is no setter for ID!

    public function hasId()
    {
        return (!empty($this->data['id']));
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->data['first_name'];
    }

    public function setFirstName($val)
    {
        $this->data['first_name'] = $val;
    }

    public function hasFirstName()
    {
        return (!empty($this->data['first_name']));
    }

    public function getMail()
    {
        return $this->data['mail'];
    }

    public function setMail($val)
    {
        $this->data['mail'] = $val;
    }

    public function hasMail()
    {
        return (!empty($this->data['mail']));
    }

    //Notice there is no getter for ID!

    public function setPassword($val)
    {
        $hashed = md5($val); //Just an example, don't do this
        $this->data['password'] = $hashed;
    }

    public function hasPassword()
    {
        return (!empty($this->data['password']));
    }

    public function save()
    {
        return $this->dep['mapper']->saveUser($this->data);
    }
}

class Mapper
{
    public function saveUser($data)
    {
        foreach($data as $field=>$value)
        {
            echo $field.': '.$value.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

try
{
    $dataFromDb = [
        'id'=>123,
        'first_name'=>'Lando',
        'mail'=>'lando@cloudcity.gov',
    ];

    $myUser = new User($dataFromDb);

    $myUser->setFirstName('Chewie');
    $myUser->setMail('wookie@kashyyyk.net');

    if(!$myUser->hasPassword())
    {
        $myUser->setPassword('AAAAAARRRRRRGHHHH');
    }

    $myUser->save();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
}
```

I prefer to do something like this, where all of the verbose boilerplate is relegated to data access objects that encapsulate the data and handle loading and saving individual records, and the app logic for individual records is contained in the main business object. They can be superclasses or traits, whatever floats your boat. Personally, I have code that writes all of my DAO and business object classes for me based on database schemas, so all I have to worry about is app logic.

```
<?php

trait UserDao
{
    private $data = [
        'id'=>null,
        'first_name'=>null,
        'mail'=>null,
        'password'=>null
    ];

    private $deps;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->data['id'];
    }

    //Notice there is no setter for ID!

    public function hasId()
    {
        return (!empty($this->data['id']));
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->data['first_name'];
    }

    public function setFirstName($val)
    {
        $this->data['first_name'] = $val;
    }

    public function hasFirstName()
    {
        return (!empty($this->data['first_name']));
    }

    public function getMail()
    {
        return $this->data['mail'];
    }

    public function setMail($val)
    {
        $this->data['mail'] = $val;
    }

    public function hasMail()
    {
        return (!empty($this->data['mail']));
    }

    private function _getPassword()
    {
        return $this->data['password'];
    }

    private function _setPassword($val)
    {
        $this->data['password'] = $val;
    }

    public function hasPassword()
    {
        return (!empty($this->data['password']));
    }

    public function load($data)
    {
        $validData = array_intersect_key($data, $this->data);

        foreach($validData as $currKey=>$currValue)
        {
            $this->data[$currKey] = $currValue;
        }
    }

    private function _save()
    {
        return $this->dep['mapper']->saveUser($this->data);
    }
}

class User
{
    use UserDao;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dep['mapper'] = new Mapper();
    }

    public function setPassword($val)
    {
        $hashed = str_rot13($val); //Just an example, don't do this
        $this->_setPassword($hashed);
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return str_rot13($this->_getPassword()); //Just an example, don't do this
    }

    public function save()
    {
        echo 'Do some complex validation here...'.PHP_EOL;

        $this->_save();
    }
}

class Mapper
{
    public function saveUser($data)
    {
        foreach($data as $field=>$value)
        {
            echo $field.': '.$value.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

try
{
    $dataFromDb = [
        'id'=>123,
        'first_name'=>'Lando',
        'mail'=>'lando@cloudcity.gov',
    ];

    $myUser = new User();
    $myUser->load($dataFromDb);

    $myUser->setFirstName('Chewie');
    $myUser->setMail('wookie@kashyyyk.net');

    if(!$myUser->hasPassword())
    {
        $myUser->setPassword('AAAAAARRRRRRGHHHH');
    }

    $myUser->save();

    echo 'Unfutzed Password: '.$myUser->getPassword().PHP_EOL;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
}
```

I recommend doing some research on this subject, there are a lot of patterns, and everyone has different opinions.